# Estimating the sum of pairwise products of four numbers subject to inequalities

Tags: inequality, optimization

Suppose that $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers such that $ab\leq m,bc\leq n,cd\leq o,da\leq p$ and $m,n,o,p$ are distinct numbers.

What is the maximum possible value of $ab+bc+cd+da$? (in terms of $m,n,o,p$)

---

We can't just add all these inequalities up and say that the maximum value is $(m+n+o+p)$, because it might not be achieved. Although it is definitely an upper bound,but not necessarily the supremum.

Comment: If $f\leq x$ and $g\leq y$ then $f+g\leq x+y$.  See if that is useful here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math in this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Very bad idea to use the letter $o$ for a variable, in general.

Comment: @JMoravitz We can't just add all these inequalities up and say that the maximum value is (m+n+o+p),because it might not be achieved.(although it is definitely an upper bound,but not the supremum)

Comment: @Roby5 then we would need additional conditions.  Trivially setting $a=b=\dots=p=1$ it is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the original version of this question where $a,b,c,d$ are constrained to satisfy:

$$ab \le m,\quad bc \le n,\quad cd \le o,\quad\text{ and }\quad da \le p$$

for some positive numbers $m, n, o, p$.

Because of symmetry in the problem, by a suitable cyclic reordering among the variables $(a,b,c,d)$ and variables $(m,n,o,p)$, we can reduce the problem
to the case $m \ge o$ and $mo \ge np$.

Let $x = ab, y = bc, z = cd, w = da$, we have

$$xz = yw = abcd \le \min( mo, np) =  np$$

This implies
$$ab + bc + cd + da \le x + n + \frac{np}{x} + p$$
As a function as $x$, the RHS is a convex function. Its maximum can only be achieved on the two extremium. i.e $x = m$ or $\displaystyle\;\frac{np}{x} = o\;$. Since $m \ge o$ and $mo \ge np$, it is easy to check the maximum of the RHS is achieved at $x = m$. From this, we find an upper bound for the expression.
$$ab + bc + cd + da \le m + n + \frac{np}{m} +p\tag{*1}$$

Notice when $(a, b, c, d) = \left( m, 1, n, \frac{p}{m}\right)$, we have

$$ab = m\le m,\quad bc = n \le n,\quad cd = \frac{np}{m} \le o\quad\text{ and }\quad da = p \le p$$
and $(*1)$ reduces to an equality for this particular $(a,b,c,d)$. This mean the upper bound in $(*1)$ is actually the maximum we seek.

From this, it is easy to see for general ordering of the variables, the maximum we seek is

$$m + n + o + p - \frac{|mo-np|}{X}\quad\text{ where }\quad
X = \begin{cases} \max(m,o), & mo \ge np\\ \max(n,p), & mo < np\end{cases}$$